# Mysql query to fetch limited rows of each type

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a Table in MYSql called companies and each companies has a type say type 1, type 2 type 3,

example :

```
id   company_name   company_type
===============================
1    test1          3
2    xyz            2
3    ashdasdjk      2 
4    test 4         1 
5    test           3 
6    ahsdkjsg       1
7    TCS            2
and so on ...
```

now  i want to write a query to fetch results such that i get 20 companies of type 1,  20 companies of type 2 and 20 companies of type 3... i mean i want to fetch maximum of 20 companies of each type

I am using Codeigniter..

Comment: What determines which 20 of each type you want to get?

Comment: i just want a query to get total 60 results of 20 of each type..

Comment: your table will contain only 60 results!... kindly brief the scenario

Comment: yes ..i want maximum of 60 results in my table out of which  there should be maximum 20 results of each type..

Comment: U Want every time same result or u want samples that wat i need to know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from (
    select
    c.*,
    @rn := if(company_type != @ct, 1, @rn + 1) as rownumber,
    @ct := company_type
    from
    companies c
    , (select @rn := 0, @ct := null) var_init
    order by
    company_type
) comp
where rownumber <= 20;
```

Comment: thanx..buddy..u r  da best person on this whole planet...can u send me some good links to learn mysql ....to improve my coding level..please.

Comment: hey.. whenevr u'll gt some tym.. cn u tell me ur logic 4 dat query? i realy lyk dat way.. bt nvr used it.. so..

Comment: You can learn more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html And a small advice: Please use proper english when you talk to someone you don't know. Some are offended, because they don't want to be treated like if they are from a ghetto. And some just think it is / looks retarded. I don't belong to neither of these groups, but I do think it's a bit disrespectful. No offense taken, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for the link and sorry for for the slang language...any ways i went through your link. i think i can understand the rest of query but just this line is what  i cant get `(select @rn := 0, @ct := null) var_init` if u could please explain ..

Comment: It's just a fancy way of initializing a variable inside a query. Writing `SET @rn := 0; SET @ct := NULL;` before the select query and omitting it in the query would have the same effect.