# what does `(SELECT @rn :=0) var_init` do?

Tags: mysql

I have seen some MySql queries using

`(SELECT @rn :=0, @ct := NULL ) var_init`

i don't know what it does  .. i have searched for it for a long time and still i don't have an answer. any help is much appreciated .

it will be much appriaced if some one could explain this query to me ...

```
SELECT  * FROM (
            SELECT c. * , @rn := IF(  `type` != @ct , 1, @rn +1 ) AS rownumber, @ct :=  `type`  FROM jb_company c , 
            (SELECT @rn :=0, @ct := NULL ) var_init ORDER BY  `type`
           ) c
WHERE rownumber <=20
```

I  am using the above query to fetch limited number of rows( i.e 20) of each type in from the table ( see the link below..for the question where i needed this )

[Mysql query to fetch limited rows of each type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399508/mysql-query-to-fetch-limited-rows-of-each-type/22399623?noredirect=1#comment34064271_22399623)

but i am still not getting the query.. some please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It plainly initializes the values (`@rn :=0, @ct := NULL`), which results in an alias `var_init` containing one row, and joins the rest on it (so, having no effect on the rows themselves other then setting up the variables in the beginning).

This is often used to avoid needing multiple statements to set up the variables. That single query is equal to:

```
SET @rn :=0;
SET @ct := NULL;
SELECT  * FROM (
    SELECT c. * ,
      @rn := IF(  `type` != @ct , 1, @rn +1 ) AS rownumber,
      @ct :=  `type`
    FROM jb_company c 
    ORDER BY  `type`
) c
WHERE rownumber <=20
```

.. which is multiple statements, so usually used due to API limitations of the using code, or to make sure the variables start out as they should be on shared connections.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expression in MySQL used to define variables that might be used in the expression.

By default, MySQL defaults variables to strings.  So, to get a numeric variable, you want to assign the variable to a number the first time it is seen.  This *can* be done in a `set` statement.  However, a "single" query would then consist of multiple statements.

Often, variables in MySQL are used to approximate the window/analytic functions available in most other databases.  Other databases do not encourage the use of such variables in queries (although they are typically allowed and can be useful under some -- more limited -- circumstances).

The query that you mention would be expressed as the following in most databases:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT c.* ,
             row_number() over (partition by `type` order by `type`) as rownumber
      FROM jb_company c
    ) c
WHERE rownumber <= 20;
```

The way the MySQL version works is by creating a derived table and using the variables to add rows with the appropriate values.